# Section{references} not appearing correctly over bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, ieeetran

I am using the tex style of SMC.

Above my reference, this appears:

```
6. * 
References
```

This instead of "6. References".

I am using their style and printing the bibliography with:

```
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{paper}
```

I went to the .sty file and I found the following entries:

```
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}

\def\thebibliography#1{
  \section{References}\list
  {[\arabic{enumi}]}{
  \settowidth\labelwidth{[#1]}\leftmargin 1em
  \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
  \usecounter{enumi}
  }
  \def\newblock{\hskip .01em plus .01em minus .01em}
  \sloppy\clubpenalty4000\widowpenalty4000
  \sfcode`\.=1000\relax
}

\let\endthebibliography=\endlist

\long\def\@makecaption#1#2{
  \vskip 10pt
  \setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{#1. #2}
  \ifdim
    \wd\@tempboxa >\hsize #1. #2\par
  \else
    \hbox
    to\hsize{\hfil\box\@tempboxa\hfil}
  \fi
}
```

I notice the problem dissapears when I comment \uspackage{amsmath}. I have tried adding \usepackage{amsrefs}, but that says the bib environment is already defined.

Here is a min working example and a [link to the style file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13564139/icmcsmc2014.sty).

```
\documentclass{article}



\usepackage{icmcsmc2014}

 \usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{filecontents}{paper_test.bib}
@article{herremans2013composing,
  title={Composing Fifth Species Counterpoint Music With A Variable Neighborhood Search Algorithm},
  author={Herremans, Dorien and S{\"o}rensen, Kenneth},
  journal={Expert Systems with Applications},
  volume={40},
  number={16},
  pages={6427--6437},
  year={2013},
  publisher={Pergamon}
}
\end{filecontents}


\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
% \usepackage{cite}
%   \usepackage{multibib}



% ***************************************** the document starts here ***************
\begin{document}



\section{Introduction}

Here I want the author name to occur with citet as it is said by \citet{herremans2013composing}.

%   \bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
%   \bibliographystyle{natbib}
  \bibliography{paper_test}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Please add a complete, minimal document allowing us to reproduce the problem. A link to the document class used (in case it's not found on CTAN) would also be useful.

Comment: You are right. I have added this.

Comment: Thnaks for adding the example. I've provided an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file `icmcsmc2014.sty` internally uses the `IEEEtran` style for the bibliography and this style is incompatible with `natbib`. You have two options:

1. Do not load `natbib` and use the defualt `IEEEtran` style for your bibliography (or course, now you cannot use `\citet` and the family of commands provided by `natbib`):

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{icmcsmc2014}
   \usepackage{amsmath}
   \usepackage{times}
   \usepackage{ifpdf}
   \usepackage[english]{babel}

   \begin{filecontents}{paper_test.bib}
   @article{herremans2013composing,
     title={Composing Fifth Species Counterpoint Music With A Variable Neighborhood Search Algorithm},
     author={Herremans, Dorien and S{\"o}rensen, Kenneth},
     journal={Expert Systems with Applications},
     volume={40},
     number={16},
     pages={6427--6437},
     year={2013},
     publisher={Pergamon}
   }
   \end{filecontents}

   \begin{document}

   \section{Introduction}
   Here I want the author name to occur with cite as it is said by \cite{herremans2013composing}.

   \bibliography{paper_test}

   \end{document}
   ```

   [image]
2. If you want to use `natbib` and its family of citation commands, then go to line 228 of `icmcsmc2014.sty` and comment out the line `\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}`. Now you can load `natbib` and you need to choose a natbib-compatible style for your bibliography in your document; in the example below I used `plainnat`. The other important thing is that you need to load `natbib` *before* `icmcsmc2014.sty`:

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
   \usepackage{icmcsmc2014}
   \usepackage{amsmath}
   \usepackage{times}
   \usepackage{ifpdf}
   \usepackage[english]{babel}

   \begin{filecontents}{paper_test.bib}
   @article{herremans2013composing,
     title={Composing Fifth Species Counterpoint Music With A Variable Neighborhood Search Algorithm},
     author={Herremans, Dorien and S{\"o}rensen, Kenneth},
     journal={Expert Systems with Applications},
     volume={40},
     number={16},
     pages={6427--6437},
     year={2013},
     publisher={Pergamon}
   }
   \end{filecontents}

   \begin{document}

   \section{Introduction}
   Here I want the author name to occur with citet as it is said by \citet{herremans2013composing}.

   \bibliographystyle{plainnat}
   \bibliography{paper_test}

   \end{document}
   ```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there any solution where I don't modify the sty file? As this is the conference's style, they will probably use the original .sty file.

Comment: In any case, loading natbib before the template already solves my section title problem. Would be nice if I could fix the authors without editing the sty file.

Comment: @dorien If they are going to use the original `.sty` file, then don't use `natbib` and its citation commands. as I mentioned in the first option. Most probably they want the citations to appear according to the `IEEEtran` style.

Comment: Yes, I do understand that. Sometimes it is useful to get the author's name printed though (even without the reference), when refering to who said something. I am not so fond of "[2] said", but I guess if there is no way, this will have to do. Your answer was very enlighting though!

Comment: Opted for your second solution in the end : ) Thanks! Hope the submission system accepts pdf : )